# Elo-like ratings for games with variable number of players

Tags: leaderboards

I read this article about using Elo for more than 2 players in a game: http://sradack.blogspot.ru/2008/06/elo-rating-system-multiple-players.html. But in my case I have a variable number of players in each match (2-10 usually) and if I just apply this logic winner of a 2-players match will have a larger rating increase than a winner of 3-players match (if we start with the same rating we will have expected {0.5, 0.5} actual {1, 0} for 2 and expected {0.33, 0.33, 0.33} actual {0.66, 0.33, 0} for 3). Are there any variations of Elo or some other systems that could handle it?

Comment: Multiply by the amount of players?

Comment: What type of game? Depending on the type of game, a viable option could _potentially_ be to treat each interaction between players as a 2-player "game" and adjust rankings during the course of the match _(e.g. after each kill in an FPS)_.

Comment: @XGundam05, it is a quiz game where players selects questions and answers them (all together). Round consists of a set of questions.